# Bluemix, Monitoring and Analytics, Application Availability, Application Response Time

Tags: ibm-cloud, monitoring

From Bluemix dashboard in 'Availability' tab, Application response time displaying for our application is around 250 msec, but whereas from chrome browser developer tool analysed for single user it is taking around 10 sec. There are around 26 requests going to server and out of them few requests are taking more than 2-3 sec individually. Does this bluemix shows the correct application response time ? We need to differentiate the Network, Application and Cloud Infrastructure(Public Cloud) performance.

Answer (score 0):

The Monitoring & Analytics service makes an http request to your application's top level ("/") URL once per minute and reports the result. This is done from a server running in IBM SoftLayer relatively close to the Bluemix environment where the application runs, so it is normally pretty quick. It therefore measures the response of the app itself rather than any network delays that might be introduced between users and the app.

If you want the type of analysis that would show you those network delays, try out the new Availability Monitoring in Bluemix. If you select the "Try the new Bluemix" link at the top of the dashboard, it will take you to the new console. From there your apps will have a "Monitoring" tab in the overview, and you can set up pings that will occur from different locations that are remote from the data center where the app actually runs. This might allow you to isolate where the delays you observe are actually being introduced.